# NetLogo: Can the value of a global variable of last two ticks be stored in a list and be called in a procedure?

Tags: memory, global-variables, netlogo, history

I want agents to remember the values of that global variable of only last ticks and I want to store them in a list and use it later wherein agents should compare the list items and take a decision for the current tick. I have tried implementing the following code but the efforts are going in vain.

```
    `set time-car_t-2 time-car of tick [n - 2]
     set time-car_t-1 time-car of last tick
     set history-time-car [list time-car_t-1 time-car_t-2 time-car_t]
```

Logic to calculate time-car is already in place and working wherein all three are global variables "time-car", "time-car_t-1" and "time-car_t-2"

Any suggestions would help and I would be grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetLogo doesn't remember past values, so it cannot give you the value of a variable (or result of a reporter) at a past tick. You need to save those values in your model as they are generated and this is normally done by using a list. In the code below, each turtle is setup with a `time-car-history` of length 5 (specified by `history-length`), that is initially filled with -1's. Then, in `test`, each turtle gets of value of `time-car` (here just a random number) and adds it to the beginning of its history.  The current value is thus `item 0` in its `time-car-history`, the value of one tick before is `item 1 time-car-history`, etc., going back four ticks.  Note that in adding the current value to `time-car-history` I drop the last value using `but-last`, so only the most recent five values are saved.  If you paste this code into a blank model, type "setup" at the command line and then repeatedly type "test", you should see how it works.

```
turtles-own [time-car-history]

to setup
  clear-all
  let history-length 5 ; the number of periods you want to save
  create-turtles 10 [
    ; creates a history list of the right length, filled with -1's.
    set time-car-history n-values history-length [-1]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to test
  ask turtles [
    set time-car-history fput time-car but-last time-car-history
  ]

  ask turtle 3 [
    show time-car-history
    show item 0 time-car-history
    show item 1 time-car-history
    show item 2 time-car-history
  ]
  tick
end

to-report time-car
  report random 10
end
```

Comment: But, I do have an extension to my question. In your example code, history-length is both a local variable and a list? and if that is the case, if I have to call the list else-where in a different procedure other than setup, like for example, "min histroy-length", it is not possible. On the other hand, making history-length a global variable and using it as setting the value to 5 will not allow me to make it a list either. Do you have any suggestions for this probelm? Hope my question is clear enough. Appreciate your support in advance. Thank you.

Comment: Shreesha, `history-length` is a local variable, set to the number 5.  It is used simply to specify the length of the `time-car-history` list, which is a turtles-own variable initialized in setup. There is no need to use `history-length` again as it is `time-car-history` which holds the information you want to be able to set and access as the model runs. I could have just used `set time-car-history n-values 5 [-1]` and not had the `history-length` variable at all, but I find it useful to give such parameters a name so it is easier to know what they mean and where to change them. Charles

Comment: By the way, if you ever need to know what the value of `history-length` was during setup, it will simply be `length time-car-history`. Charles

Comment: Hello Mr. Charles, As an extension to the question, after storing the values in the list as well as updating the list with the latest values, suppose I want to choose time-car as the "mean" value of all the 5 time-car values stored in the list, is it possible? I understand we cannot apply mathematical operations like mean and all to the list of items. Any alternate suggestion to achieve this would also help. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Shreesha, `mean` is designed to work on lists, so `mean time-car-history` will give you the average of the 5 entries in the list, which is to say the average of the most recent 5 observations.  This mean would, of course, be for a given turtle.  If you wanted the mean over all turtles, that is easy to get too, with `mean [mean time-car-history] of turtles`, i.e., the mean of the means.